# d3js Text Transitioin - example code not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

I am new to d3.js and trying to execute some of the example codes given in the d3 examples. I tried copying the Text Transition-1 ([link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7004f92cac972edef365)) example code. But came across this error in the console

> text-transition.html:26 Uncaught TypeError:
>   d3.select(...).transition(...).duration(...).on is not a function

Here is the code I executed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Text Transition animation 1</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            h1 {
              font: 400 120px/500px "Helvetica Neue";
              text-align: center;
              width: 960px;
              height: 500px;
              margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>0</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("the script is executing")
            var format = d3.format(",d");

            d3.select("h1")
              .transition()
                .duration(2500)
                .on("start", function repeat() {

                  d3.active(this)
                      .tween("text", function() {
                        var that = d3.select(this),
                            i = d3.interpolateNumber(that.text().replace(/,/g, ""), Math.random() * 1e6);
                        return function(t) { that.text(format(i(t))); };
                      })
                    .transition()
                      .delay(1500)
                      .on("start", repeat);
                });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The d3js version I am using is 3.5.17. Executing the snippet on Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is seems to be with the d3 version.

Try using `<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.23.min.js"></script>`.

Source: http://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.23.min.js

```js
console.log("the script is executing")
var format = d3.format(",d");

d3.select("h1")
  .transition()
  .duration(2500)
  .on("start", function repeat() {

    d3.active(this)
      .tween("text", function() {
        var that = d3.select(this),
          i = d3.interpolateNumber(that.text().replace(/,/g, ""), Math.random() * 1e6);
        return function(t) {
          that.text(format(i(t)));
        };
      })
      .transition()
      .delay(1500)
      .on("start", repeat);
  });
```

```css
h1 {
  font: 400 120px/500px"Helvetica Neue";
  text-align: center;
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.23.min.js"></script>
<h1>0</h1>
```

Comment: Weird how it doesn't work with the most up to date version

Comment: Here's the working fiddle with Gilsha's suggestion:http://jsfiddle.net/a2QpA/316/

Comment: @thatOneGuy [`transition.on()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_on) is new to v4 and acts as a replacement for [`transition.each()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Transitions#each) of v3, which in v4 will be equivalent to `selection.each()`.