# d3js Text Transition I example with v3 library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I am trying to replicate the example [in this link](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7004f92cac972edef365) written in d3.js v4 with d3.js v3 since my application is old and I can not change the library. But when I try to run it with older versiob, I get the following error:

```
d3.select(...).transition(...).duration(...).on is not a function
```

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272281/d3js-text-transitioin-1-example-code-not-working) here has mentioned the very same issue but sadly it doesn't explain how to replicate this example with v3. Although I did learn that the problem is that transition.on() is new to v4.

So can some one please help me porting this example back to v3.

```js
var format = d3.format(",d");

d3.select("h1")
  .transition()
  .duration(2500)
  .each("start", function repeat() {
    d3.active(this)
      .tween("text", function() {
        var that = d3.select(this),
          i = d3.interpolateNumber(that.text().replace(/,/g, ""), Math.random() * 1e6);
        return function(t) {
          that.text(format(i(t)));
        };
      })
      .transition()
      .delay(1500)
      .each("start", repeat);
  });
```

```css
h1 {
  font: 400 120px/500px "Helvetica Neue";
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<h1>0</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a minimal example of transitioning a number in version 3 of d3. For further functionality like formatting and retransitioning to initial number, look at this example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/a0c5ef180272fac3aea6).

```js
d3.selectAll("h1").transition().duration(1500).delay(0)
    .tween("text", function(d) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(0, 4000);
      return function(t) {
        d3.select(this).text((i(t)));
      };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<h1>0</h1>
```